# Weird values from ADS1115 chip and remote I/0 error

Tags: potentiometer, error

I am using a ADS1115 chip to read the values from a potentiometer and then transfer them to a raspberry pi zero w.

I wired the potentiometers, so that on the left would be the lowest. GND - DATA - VDD. When I try to read these values it seems to work, when the potentiometers aren´t at the very beginning or end. Then I read values from 5 - 400. But when they are at the very end/beginning I read values like -1 or even 32000 or I get remote I/O errors.

What causes this?

Comment: Remote IO error? Check connections. It's 16 bit. Thus 65536 values. So 32000 is close to the middle of the range. Also, can you actually display data in unsigned format rather than signed? It's hard to tell what -1 is. Cast whatever you receive to uint16_t.

Comment: I/O Error #121? That means wires too long, ... etc.

Comment: but how? The wires arent longer than 20cm at max

Comment: More causes of I2C I/O Error #121: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly

Answer (score 0):

ADS1115 input range should go all the way to GND reference, so it sounds like you have a ground potential  difference either with the chip GND and the signal to be measured. Or between the reference signal, if you are using a differential measurement.

The higher end error similarly would be the signal being higher than specified maximum voltage. The range you have set by setting up the programmable gain amplifier.

Just to be sure not to hit the very ends of the range you could add fixed resistors to both ends of the potentiometer. If you select them to be 1 % of the potentiometer max value you won't be losing much resolution either.

"-1" or other errors could be because the library you are using returns it when it has read an alert from the chip, if you've wired and set that up.